# How to scrape information from multiple sublinks of a scraped url BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

 page = requests.get('https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=15')
 soup = Soup(page.content, 'html.parser')

 details = soup.find_all('a')
 #print(details[0])
 details_arr = []
 for i in details:
   details_arr.append()
```

Page is the link. On the page are "details" which if clicked go to a different link. If I want to scrape the information from the details links how do i do that without manually copying and pasting each website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin

URL  = 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=15'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

#get all the links within the first column 
details = soup.select('td[class="hidden-print"] a')
#loop through them and convert the link from relative link to absolute 
details_urls  = [urljoin(URL,link.get('href')) for link in details]
print(details_urls)
```

Output:

```
['https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571155', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571157', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571158', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571159', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571163', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571164', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571165', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571168', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571169', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571171', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571172', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571173', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571174', 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=853571175', ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But if you can clarify, what does the headers variable do? Why is it needed?

Comment: @ap1k the header's user-agent tells the server which device and browser you are using to access it . if the answer helped you please accept it .